# Speed Up download time

Tags: android, io, filereader

I have 40 MB file in server and i am downloading my file using

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
 c.setRequestMethod("GET");
 c.setDoOutput(true);
 c.connect();
 FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("trips.xml"));


 InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int len1 = 0;
 while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
  f.write(buffer,0, len1);
```

this code seems working fine but it is taking too long. is their any way I can make this process faster.

/minhaz

Comment: You can only download as fast as the slowest connection.  If you're on dialup (56K), optimization won't matter.  And the slowest connection won't necessarily be you - it's not a direct connection to the server, the requests travel over numerous networks to get there and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This <strike>very ugly hack which</strike> *might* give you a faster download time, or maybe it doesn't, you'll have to test it under your conditions:

Start several parallel connections (in separate threads?), and each one should download a different chunk of data (using [HTTP 1.1 Range header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)).  Depending on many things like if there's a full moon, or the sun is out or the roses are blooming you might get better results because it will saturate your link better than a single connection (to the expense of everyone else sharing your link, kinda like what BitTorrent does).

Comment: This is how download accelerators and managers typically work.  I wouldn't call this an ugly hack, I would call it a pretty good solution ;-)

Comment: @Chris OK, I guess that part was really subjective.  I'll fix that.

Comment: @Gianni I suppose in the perspective of everybody else you're supposed to be _sharing_ bandwidth with, it's definitely ugly... ;-)

Comment: @Chris the reason I called it an ugly hack is that in theory, you should trust the network to give you the best results; always.  The reason this thing works is by exploiting how routers and load balancers across the network share and limit usage to a link.

Comment: Ah I see where you're coming from.  Either way, I think you specified one of the more effective solutions.

Comment: @Chris, do not write about effectivity before testing. I have strong faith my answer with buffer size will trurly help you. It worked for me in identical case.

Comment: @tomash Actually, they are both complementary.

Comment: @tomash Sorry, didn't mean to offend.  I was speaking generally with regards to increasing the number of connections versus some other, nondescript solution, not other solutions mentioned here. As Gianni points out, there's no reason they can't work together.  Also, I'm not the one who asked the original question so whether it works for me or not is irrelevant ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use larger input buffer than 1 KB. The faster you empty buffer, the faster network stack can continue downloading. This should help:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[50*1024];
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to get a nice increase on download speeds; initially I was using a 1kb buffer, then 8kb, but then I tried 50kb and it made a significant difference.

Comment: Extremely practical solution

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem, came up with this code.  Was faster than  previous versions I have tried.  I specify a buffer size greater than the file I am going to down load.  Hope it helps.

```
    public String load(String url, int bufferSize){

    try {
        URL myURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
        ucon.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        InputStream inputStream = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        ByteArrayBuffer byteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(bufferSize);
        byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read;
        do {
            read = bufferedInputStream.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            if (read > 0)
                byteArrayBuffer.append(buf, 0, read);
        } while (read >= 0);
        return new String(byteArrayBuffer.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Error", e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is along the right lines, in that a bigger buffer size is needed.  However, one should avoid a buffer size greater than the file size for files larger than a couple megabytes due to memory constraints on mobile devices.